Exclude products with specific metadata from WooCommerce recent products widget
I am currently trying to exclude specific products from the WooCommerce recent products widget.
Specifically, I want to prevent products with specific metadata from being displayed: Meta key _age_limit set to “大人向け” (Adult) meta value.
The widget that I wish to exclude adult products from is "Newest Products," and it is placed on the Front Page (see the screenshot below).

I added the following code to my functions.php, but it’s not working as expected:
add_filter('woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'exclude_adult_products_from_recent_products', 10, 3);
function exclude_adult_products_from_recent_products($query_args, $atts, $loop_name){
    if( $loop_name == 'recent_products' ){
        $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_age_limit',
            'value' => '大人向け',
            'compare' => '!=',
        );
    }
    return $query_args;
}

The _age_limit is the meta key used for a product custom field.
The theme I’m using is the official WooCommerce Storefront theme and get the latest WordPress and WooCommerce versions.
I have confirmed that the tags are correctly stored in the database, and when I tested the SQL query directly in phpMyAdmin, it returned the expected results. Here is the SQL query I used:
SELECT * FROM ierd_postmeta WHERE meta_key = ‘_age_limit’ AND meta_value = ‘大人向け’;

The query successfully returns the expected products with the tag “大人向け.” However, the WooCommerce filter code doesn’t seem to exclude these products from the recent products widget.
Below is how I added the custom meta field for age limit in functions.php:：
function custom_product_general_fields() {
    woocommerce_wp_select( array(
        'id'      => '_age_limit',
        'label'   => __( 'Age Limit', 'woocommerce' ),
        'options' => array(
            '全年齢'   => __( '全年齢', 'woocommerce' ),
            '大人向け' => __( '大人向け', 'woocommerce' ),
        ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'custom_product_general_fields' );

I am really struggling with this issue, and I’m not sure why this filter isn’t working as expected.
It's quite problematic that adult products are being displayed on the front page, and I'm concerned about it.
Any advice on how to debug or resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT
As suggested, I also tried using woocommerce_products_widget_query_args hook instead like:
function exclude_adult_products_from_newest_widget($query_args) { 
    // Applicable only for front page
    if (is_front_page()) {

        // Initialize a metaquery or retrieve an existing query
        $meta_query = isset($query_args['meta_query']) ? $query_args['meta_query'] : array();

        // Exclude products with metafield _age_limit value "For adults"
         $query_args['meta_query'][]= array(
            'key'     => '_age_limit',
            'value'   => '大人向け',
            'compare' => '!='
        );
        
    }
    
    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', 'exclude_adult_products_from_newest_widget');

But it didn’t work even after clearing the browser cache…

One thing off about your code is this line:
$meta_query = isset($query_args['meta_query']) ? $query_args['meta_query'] : array();

So I see that you assigned the value for $meta_query, but never used it, and leave the risk of $query_args['meta_query'] being undefined.
I suggest you try this:
function exclude_adult_products_from_newest_widget($query_args) {
    // Applicable only for front page
    if (is_front_page()) {
        
        // Assign empty array to $query_args['meta_query'] if it is undefined
        if(!isset($query_args['meta_query']) || !is_array($query_args['meta_query'])){
            $query_args['meta_query'] = array();
        }
        // Exclude products with metafield _age_limit value "For adults"
         $query_args['meta_query'][]= array(
            'key'     => '_age_limit',
            'value'   => '大人向け',
            'compare' => '!='
        );

    }
    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', 'exclude_adult_products_from_newest_widget', 99, 1);

Another edit I added is to add priority to add_filter(). If the above code doesn't work, you may want to adjust that number.

Unfortunately, it’s not working... umm...It might be an error caused by the recent WooCommerce update.
